# Using trigonometry to shoot multiple bullets like a shotgun

Tags: android, trigonometry, angle

I'm making a game where the player follows the mouse and a bullet gets shot out the players back end at the opposite direction that it is moving towards the mouse. Its a bit hard to explain in words so i quickly made a rough draft in paint.net to demonstrate.

Grey ball is the player. yellow cursor is where the player is touching on the touch screen. And the black balls are the bullets.

In example 1 and 2, the player is moving towards the cursor and bullets are behind shot in the opposite direction. What I want to o is like in example 3 where there is more than one bullet coming out the back and they are also spread out like a shotgun shot.

image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Q18.png
[image]

My goal would be to allow the player to upgrade to be able to shoot more than one bullet at a time. All I want is for the player to be able to shoot up to 5 at a time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using an engine of some kind? In any case, how are the balls being moved? By steps of X and Y? By angle and distance/speed? Other?

Comment: Have you written any code yet for this app?

Comment: im making this in java on android. This is how I manage how the bullet moves when I shoot a single bullet: `x += Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;
     y += Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;`

Comment: Yes I have written code. Also the angle in my formula is the players angle.

Comment: If you need more help understanding what I want, there is a flash game I used to play that used the same concept: http://www.kongregate.com/games/gamereclaim/death-vs-monstars

Answer (score 1):

The angles of the other bullets would use the same formula you are using, but the angles would be some constant offset relative to the center bullet. For instance, if you are using the following formula for the center bullet:

```
x += Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed; 
y += Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;
```

then your other bullets would be:

```
x1 += Math.cos((angle + 10) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed; 
y1 += Math.sin((angle + 10) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;


x2 += Math.cos((angle - 10) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed; 
y2 += Math.sin((angle - 10) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;
```

You can choose some other value other than 10 if you so choose. If you wanted to shoot 5 at a time, you would also use:

```
x3 += Math.cos((angle + 20) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed; 
y3 += Math.sin((angle + 20) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;


x4 += Math.cos((angle - 20) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed; 
y4 += Math.sin((angle - 20) * Math.PI/180) * Status.bulletSpeed;
```

Here, the number you use should be twice the value you choose for the first set.

Comment: You could also offset the angle by a randomised amount, rather than a set offset

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it as soon as i get the chance and I'll tell you how it went. Now that I look at it the solution looks obvious. I'm in secondary 4 and I'm only learing trig in a few months in school so these concepts are still new to me but thanks for simplifying it so I can understand.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: It worked, I dont know how to set as correct, I cant upvote either